# How to use Html Helper methods in .razor file in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I recently started learning Blazor in .net core and I noticed I couldn't use the HTML Helper methods in the .razor file. Is there something I'm missing?
I keep getting an error like "the name Html does not exist in the context".

What do I do?

Comment: I don't think they are supported in Blazor. You need to find an alternative or learn blazor components. [See docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#:~:text=Blazor%20apps%20are%20based%20on,NET%20C%23%20classes%20built%20into%20.)

Comment: HTML Helper methods are used to output raw HTML to the client from the server.  Blazor is a framework for _manipulating_ the already rendered output client-side.  These are not compatible techniques.

Comment: Components in Blazor are reusable parts, perfect for it. No HTML helper or the equivalent needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use @helper directive anymore, you can create a Nested components **Shared\Heading.razor** and call it in the same razor component or other pages.

```
<h1 style="font-style:@headingFontStyle">Heading Example</h1>
<Heading />
@code {
    private string headingFontStyle = "italic";
}
```

or

```
@page "/heading-example"

<Heading />
```

See this document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) for more details